# How to access current user in Laravel Models (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel

I want to check if current user has liked particular question or not, and store the result (boolean) to the appended attribute as follows:

In my Question Model

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


  public function usersWhoLikedThis()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'question_user_likes');
}
  public function getHasLikedAttribute() {
    return $this->usersWhoLikedThis->contains(Auth::user()->id);
}
```

The above approach doesn't work,
when i, dd(Auth::user()->id) i get null

My goal is to return a list of questions,where each question has 'has_liked' attribute which will be true if current user liked the question, and false if otherwise

Comment: If `Auth::user()->id` is `null` then the `user` is not logged in, so is anyone who is not logged in, you have to protect that route with middlewares that only allow logged in users.

Comment: you're probably calling it at a place where the auth middleware hasn't ran yet

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are writing `$this->usersWhoLikedThis->contains(Auth::user()->id)`, but the `usersWhoLikedThis` collection will contain `User` models, not their IDs. So what you want to do is:

```php
public function getHasLikedAttribute() {
    return $this->usersWhoLikedThis->contains(Auth::user());
}
```

As a bonus, you don't need to check if the user is logged in or not, because it will just return false for guests.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller search to see if it exists but database will take of that you can also do it in your model

```
public function index(Question $question) {
    $isLiked = $question->usersWhoLikedThis()->where('user_id',auth()->id())->exists();
}
```